# How to test for significant differences between datasets in Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, significance

I want to test for significant differences between several datasets in the experimenter, but i only manage to perform the T-Test on the different algorithms. How can i do a significance test to compare the results on multiple datasets?

So are the results on dataset A significantly better than on dataset B (with the same Algorithm)

Comment: Difference of what? Of the means?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, eg accuracy or fmeasure

Comment: Accuracy or fmeasure of what? For example, you can apply one algorithm to several datasets (let us say, they are all for classification task) and then compare accuracy. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apart from the fact that my question was apparently not clear enough (sorry for that) I just solved it myself now. Sorry for asking but it was somewhat urgent.
For those seeking for quick help with the same problem as I did, here is the simple answer:

Just press the Button `Swap` in the "Select rows and cols" line in the Analyse Section.